# Buttons on sheet that used to work fine now linking to different code script files?

Tags: google-apps-script

Buttons on sheet that used to work fine now link to different code script files?!
Most of the buttons still have the correct script names assigned but the links seem to have got corrupted!

For example, the user clicks the 'Create Invoice' button (with the correct function name 'CreateInvoice' function name assigned) and it appears to succesfully create the invoice (in pdf format) but attaches it to the email message from the 'CreateCreditNote' function.

I also now have one button that is assigned to a script which no longer seems to exist (but still works fine). Therefore I cannot access/edit it.

1. All my functions have unique names
2. This has only recently started to happen, with the last major action being Enabling Chrome V8 runtime

A (sort of) fix: I renamed the (only) function in an affected script and copied it into a new script file (with the same name as the function). I then assigned the new function name to the original button - it works!

I really don't want to be forced to do this for all my script files - this seems to be a major bug - what is going on?

Would anyone know how to contact a real member of Google Sheets App script development team?

Comment: What was the last action you did on the script files or in Google Apps Script before the links became different? Are you using the same function names on different files?

Comment: Hi Carlos - the last major action was Enabling Chrome V8 runtime

Comment: What do you mean by "link to different code script files"? How do you noticed that? Are there errors logged in the executions page? If so, add the textual errors. Have you signed in in multiple Google accounts or just on a single account? Does your spreadsheet has bounded multiple projects?

Comment: What happens if you disable the V8 runtime ?

Comment: I've edited my question further.
No errors that I can see.
This has just two users.
Single bound project
Tried disabling V8 - but it says it won't effect this deployment

Comment: It looks that Google is rolling out a change in the Google Sheets UI (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/66857421/1595451)  that might caused a glitch. If the problem is not reproducible then the question is not on-topic here it could be discussed in the Google Apps Script community

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that the cause of the problem is that the project has several functions with the same name.

All the files on a single project share the same global scope. While adding the file might apparently solved the problem what it's happening is that it is being loaded at last and overwriting the functions with the same name loaded previously.

Using the same function name several times on a single project isn't a good practice. The basic solution is to avoid this, in other words, review your project and change the name of the functions that use name already used. Another option is the use of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: Hi Ruben - many thanks for your response.
1. All my functions have unique names
2. This has only recently started to happen.
3. I have one button that is assigned to script which no longer seems to exist (but works fine)