# Google Apps Script asks for permissions every week

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a script in Google Apps Script that needs permissions for "Connect to an external service" and "See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Sheets spreadsheets". I also use Google Cloud Logging for the script's log. It runs every 1 min by trigger.

It mostly works fine but about a week after I give permissions, it fails for permission error. Then, if I give permission again (by running the function in the editor view, then giving permissions), it starts working in the intended way, but it fails again one week after that.

How could I fix this?

I tried reducing the frequency of the run, but still there is the same issue.

Comment: How many sheets?

Comment: Is your script bound to a standard GCP project?

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66859421/7577786 This thread explains why, basically the OAuth for GCP projects in testing mode expire every 7 days.